# Homogeneous differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}$ solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{x}$. So I set $v = \dfrac{y}{x}$ and so
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = v
$$
Then by product rule $x\dfrac{dv}{dx} + v = v$ and so $x\dfrac{dv}{dx} = 0$. But then that means there is no unique solution to the differential equation; am I wrong in my reasoning?

Wolframalpha said the solution was $y(x) = cx$.

Comment: Since $\frac{dv}{dx}=0$, you know that $v(x)=c$ for all x, for some constant c.  Now you can substitute back for v.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach 1**

$$\dfrac{dy}{y} = \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Integrate each side and simplify, you get:

$$y = c x$$

**Approach 2**

This is your approach, we get:

$$v' x = 0 \rightarrow v = c$$

From the initial substitution, you have:

$$v = \dfrac{y}{x} \rightarrow y = v x = cx$$

In other words, both methods yield the same family of curves and your reasoning is correct.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve it with this method. Why does the other method fail?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti!

Comment: Neither method fails. And they both give the same family of answers.

Comment: @Amzoti How did you know that $v' x=0$? I see the OP said that tis came by the product rule, but what did he apply the product rule on?

Comment: @Ovi: We have $v = y/x \rightarrow y = vx$ and by the product rule $dy/dx = v + v'x$. From the start, we have $dy/dx = v$, thus equating leads to $v = v + v'x$ or $v'x = 0$. Is that clear now?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes thank you very much!

Comment: @Ovi: you are very welcome! Regards

Answer (score 1):

${\frac{dy}{dx}}={\frac{y}{x}}$

${\frac{dy}{y}}={\frac{dx}{x}}$

Integrating

${\ln}y={\ln}x+C$,

where $C$ is an integration constant.

${\ln}y={\ln}x+{\ln}a$

${\ln}y={\ln}(ax)$

$y=ax$

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which was "am I wrong in my reasoning?"