# General solution using separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ok I have the equation:

$$
R\frac{dq(t)}{dt} + \frac{q(t)}{C} - V = 0
$$

and have been asked to find the general solution using separation of variables. I am unsure if I am rearranging the the equation correctly. Here is my attempt:

$$
CR \ dq(t) = (-q(t) + VC) \  dt
$$

Which then I integrate both sides giving me:

$$
CR \ q(t)=-q(t)t+VCt
$$

Which I rearrange in terms of q(t):

$$
q(t) = \frac{VCt}{CR+t}
$$

I just wanted to confirm I performed the steps correctly. Alot of the online examples are in terms of $x$ and $y$, seeing the $dq(t)$ has really confused my perspective of the solution.

Thanks

Comment: You could always use find and replace on a text edit to perform $q\to y$.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but then would $\frac{dq(t)}{dt}$ equal $y'$? If so then there's only one 'function' in the equation?

Comment: Yes, the notation $\dfrac{dq(t)}{dt}$ is short for $\dfrac{dq}{dt}(t)$ which is the derivative of $q$ evaluated at $t$, just like $q'(t)$.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that when I integrate both sides, I'm integrating a function $q(t)$ and treating it like a variable, whereas it should have some sort of function with respect to $t$ within it. Am I correct in assuming it's a variable and just integrating it?

Comment: Very nice observation. Your question is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483501/why-is-it-legitimate-to-solve-the-differential-equation-fracdydx-fracy). TL.DR: you can treat as a variable, it works, even though it doesn't make sense.

Comment: In differential equations, functions _are_ among the "variables"...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner But they are variables of a different order-type than what the OP is talking about.

Comment: I am using the term in the sense of what the method is called -- it _is_ a little strange to say "separation of variables", as much as doing so in the method "variation of parameters".  These, I believe, are survivals of terminology from the early history of differential equation study.

Comment: I wonder if this has a cleaner interpretation with nonstandard analysis / hyperreals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "variables", which are $ \ q \ $ and $ \ t \ $ , have not actually been separated in your expression:  you need to divide $ \ CR \ dq = (-q(t) + VC) \  dt \ $  through to write

$$
 \frac{dq}{q \ -  \ VC} \ = \  -\frac{1}{CR} \  dt \ \ ,
$$

before proceeding to integrate both sides.  This can now be accomplished with a $ \ u-$ substitution.

Comment: Thankyou for that, I just had an epiphany when I replaced the $q(t)$ with $y$ and realised that there is no dependant $t$ variable as with most $x$ and $y$ examples. That really helps, thanks again.

Comment: Epiphanies are always good -- I'm glad this was helpful.