# Integrate this how? $\int {\frac {y(x)' (1-y(x)^2)}{y(x)^3}} dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to solve a differential equation but I get to the point in which I have to solve this:
$$\int {\frac {y(x)' (1-y(x)^2)}{y(x)^3}} dx$$

I don't understand how to do it. I think it's related to some property I don't know, but the $y(x)'$ is throwing me off. I tried looking at Wolfram's step by step but I don't understand it.
Thanks for any help.

Context: Original function to solve is $(v^3) du + (u^3-uv^2) dv = 0$. 
I used a variable change: $y = \dfrac uv$. I'm not sure if it's correct or anything though.

Comment: What is the differential equation you're trying to solve? How does this integral come up? If you're using separation of variable there shouldn't be a $y'$ in any integral.

Comment: Hint: use the chain rule.

Comment: Also welcome to MSE!

Comment: @DavidH Oh, I always forget the chain rule for integrals. Thanks!

Comment: And @DanZimm I used first a change of variables, edited the question for context if you're curious :). And thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Perhaps of interest is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483501) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the obvious change of variables $y=y(x) \implies dy=y'(x)\,dx$, your integral becomes:

$$\int {\frac {y(x)' (1-y(x)^2)}{y(x)^3}} dx=\int {\frac {1-y^2}{y^3}} dy\\
=\int y^{-3}dy-\int y^{-1}dy\\
=-\frac12 y^{-2}-\log{y}+constant$$

Comment: Oh, that was very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation simplifies a lot if you use $$u(v)=\frac{v}{y(v)}$$ (which is basically the reciprocal of what you chose).

After replacement and simplifications (there are several), you should arrive to $$1-v y(v) \frac{dy(v)}{dv}=0$$ for which the solution is simply $$y(v)= \sqrt{c_1+2\log (v)}$$ from which $$u(v)=\frac{v}{\sqrt{c_1+2 \log (v)}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's easier that way.

Comment: You are really welcome. I don't have any merit since I noticed that after your change of variable the equation was almost as complex as the initial one. So, I took the reciprocal ! Cheers and again welcome to this site.